# Angular2: ng-content attributes passing to child component

Tags: angular, parameter-passing, projection

Is something like this possible?

I want to pass an "hasfocus" variable from cjc-box through ng-content attributes to the cjc-input component.

app.component.html

```
<div cjc-box><div cjc-input></div></div>
```

cic-box.component.html

```
<div class="cjc-box">
  <div><ng-content hasfocus="focus"></ng-content></div>
</div>
```

cic-input.component.html

```
<input class="cjc-input" type="text" focus="{{hasfocus}}" />
```

Is this even possible with projections in ng2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to pass variable to projected content (assuming component `cjc-box` declares property `focus` and component `cjc-input` declares property `hasfocus`):

```
<div cjc-box #box><div cjc-input [hasfocus]="box.focus"></div></div>
```

This is one-way binding, if you want two-way it is slightly more complex:

- Add `@Input()` decorator to `focus` property of box component.
- Add `@Input()` decorator to `hasfocus` property of input component
- Add `@Output() hasfocusChange:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();` to input component.
- Add `this.hasfocusChange.emit(this.hasfocus);` after `hasfocus` change in your input component.
- Change template to `<div cjc-box #box><div cjc-input [(hasfocus)]="box.focus"></div></div>`

Comment: That was easy! Thank you!

Comment: Now i get the value for hasfocus in the cjc-input component, great! But when i change the value inside the cjc-input component then its not changing in parent component (cjc-box). 
It looks as if it would be a copy rather than a reference. :(

Comment: Could you explain why this is necessary: "Add @Input() decorator to focus property of box component."