# Angular2: Bind with child component through ng-content

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular2-ngcontent

I try to make a few components that work together for my app.

Short explanation:

```
<tile>
  <tile-filters></tile-filters>
  <tile-search></tile-search>
</tile>
```

My goal is to set a property on the `tile` component which then is used in the child components. I use `ng-content` in the `tile` component so I can place the child components in correct order and to be able to bind properties automatically so I don't have to do that everywhere I use these components.

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671223/angular2-ng-content-attributes-passing-to-child-component), but I don't like it that I have to manually bind all the properties in the HTML in `app.ts`, as then I will have to do that everywhere where I want to use this.

I have added `showFilters="showFilters"` or tried `[showFilters]="showFilters"` to the `ng-content` which doesn't work as it will say that `showFilters` it isn't a known property of `ng-content`.

Is there a way to do this, so I don't have to set it all the time when using the component. Something with `@ContentChilds` or events?

How I want it to work is that when I click on a button in the `tile-filters` component that it gets closed and `tile-search` will update so it will take full width. When I then click on a button on `tile-search` it should show the `tile-filters` again and both share the space. (In future I want to add more components which work with the same properties)

Below examples of the components or a working [Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/PVSJRaqcOma4ZIn7JzyH?p=preview).

**tile.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'tile',
  template: `
    <div class="row">
      <ng-content select="tile-filters" showFilters="showFilters"></ng-content>
      <ng-content select="tile-search" showFilters="showFilters"></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class TileComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() showFilters: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.showFilters == null) {
      this.showFilters = false;
    }
  }

}
```

**tile-filters.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'tile-filters',
  template: `
    <section class="tile" *ngIf="showFilters">
      <div class="tile-header dvd dvd-btm">
        <h3 class="custom-font">Search Filters</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="close()">Close</button>
      </div>
      <div class="tile-body">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
    </section>
  `
})
export class TileFiltersComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() showFilters: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.showFilters = true;
  }

  close() {
    this.showFilters = false;
  }

}
```

**tile-search.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'tile-search',
  template: `
    <section class="tile">
      <div class="tile-body">
        <button class="btn btn-primary left-side" (click)="openFilters()">
          Search options
        </button>
        <div class="input-container">
          <input type="text"
                 name="TileSearch"
                 autocomplete="off"
                 class="form-control"
                 placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
                 [(ngModel)]="query">
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  `
})
export class TileSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() showFilters: boolean;
  @Input() placeholder: string;
  @Input() query: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openFilters() {
    this.showFilters = true;
  }

}
```

And to put it all together
**app.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="page">
      <tile [showFilters]="showFilters">
        <tile-filters class="col-md-3">
          My awesome filters
        </tile-filters>

        <tile-search [ngClass]="{'col-md-9': showFilters, 'col-md-12': !showFilters}" 
                     [placeholder]="placeholder" 
                     [query]="query">
        </tile-search>
      </tile>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  showFilters: boolean;
  placeholder: string;
  query: string;

  constructor() {
    this.showFilters = true;
    this.placeholder = 'Enter search query here';

  }
}
```

Comment: I would like just to leave you a recommendation, migrating to Angular 4 could help you in many scenarios, this is one. Check how simple it is to  bind components even from different modules with `NgComponentOutlet`: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgComponentOutlet-directive.html

Comment: Hm, thanks for the tip. I'll look into that.